# adding same class to div using another divs class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need your help. I´m totally new to javascript but i was able to make a website using some functions. Now my question is:

All in all i got 77 divs and 77 paths. I want every path to get the same class as the div that belongs to the path. Every div and every path has its own ID. My index markup looks like this:

```
<div id="div_1" class="div_class_1"></div>
<div id="div_2" class="div_class_2"></div>
<div id="div_3" class="div_class_3"></div>
<div id="div_4" class="div_class_4"></div>
  ....
<div id="div-77"></div>

<div id="map">
  <path id="path_1" class="get class from #div_1"></path>
  <path id="path_2" class="get class from #div_2"></path>
  <path id="path_3" class="get class from #div_3"></path>
  <path id="path_4" class="get class from #div_4"></path>
    ...
  <path id="path_77" class="get class from #div_77"></path>
</div>
```

So basically when the page is loaded i want the function to read the class of #div_1 to add it as class for #path_1.

Comment: If your path elements under a div with a specified class do not have explicit class or style attributes set, then wouldn't they automatically use the same class or style as their parent div?  Either way, do you want a function that will accept a div identifier, determine its class, and update the path descendents of the specified div with such?

Comment: I need a function that says that the path with id="path-x" has to have the same class as the div with id="div-x".

Comment: Are you looking to run this automatically after a page is loaded?  You might consider breaking down the logic you desire, step by step so that it will be clear to others.  e.g. - (1) get all divs in a document, (2) for each div, get all path elements, (3) for each path element, set the class name to that of the parent div

Comment: i updated my previous post. Hope this makes it a little bit more easy to understand.

Comment: You might re-evaluate your app structure. Classes, by definition, are sets of like things. Ask yourself why you need to address each of those elements individually instead of using an abstracted function.

Comment: I need this function because the divs are getting her classes via php from a json-file located on a server. So everytime there is a change the class changes, too maybe. But i need the path to have the updated class because different classes have different styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over div elements and update your path class elements based on the div id, here is a working example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#divs').children('div').each( function () {
    
      var index = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
      console.log(index);
      
      $('#path_' + index).addClass($(this).attr("class"));
    
    });
    
    console.log($('#map').html());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divs">
  <div id="div_1" class="div_class_1"></div>
  <div id="div_2" class="div_class_2"></div>
  <div id="div_3" class="div_class_3"></div>
  <div id="div_4" class="div_class_4"></div>
  <div id="div_77" class="div_class_77"></div>
</div>

<div id="map">
  <path id="path_1" class=""></path>
  <path id="path_2" class=""></path>
  <path id="path_3" class=""></path>
  <path id="path_4" class=""></path>
  <path id="path_77" class=""></path>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

look at this example.

you can get the class of an element using this method

```
elm = document.getElementById('item');
var cName = elm.className;
```

and you can change the classname on the fly this way.

```
elm.className = 'inactive'; // class name inactive will be applied to the selected element
```

create a for loop then you can get ,apply or remove classes on the fly.

Comment: but with this method i need to add the class manually. I want the js to read the class of the div and add it automatically to the pass.